# Choosing reference types between assemblies and NuGet packages

Tags: c#, reference, .net-assembly, nuget-package

In Visual Studio, I am isolating a project and migrating an existing project's dependencies from "project dependencies" to NuGet packages.
I have dependencies like Microsoft.CSharp and System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation. They are not .Net Framework dependencies. I see those are available both as assemblies as well as NuGet packages.
While both should work in this project, what would be the advantages and disadvantages to use assemblies reference vs Nuget Package references?
Thank you.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Not really. The reference in my case is neither my own project nor a project reference.

Comment: If your project targets .NET Framework, assemblies from .NET Framework reference assemblies are preferred. Those NuGet packages are mainly for .NET Core scenarios. It is a case-by-case thing, and for your current question you don't need the NuGet packages.

Comment: According to their own blog, it's just an alternative which lets you get fixes released sooner https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/p/nugetpackages/